# What does "if flawed" mean in "interesting, if flawed, concept"?

Tags: idioms

I'm not a native English speaker. I was reading some article and it said:

> "interesting, if flawed, concept".

What does "if flawed" mean in this sentence? Does it mean the concept is interesting and flawed (wrong?)? I can't quite understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is the seventh sense of *if* as given in Oxford's Advanced Learner's Dictionary:

> ***[if](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/if)*** 7: used before an adjective to introduce a contrast
>
> > He's a good driver, if a little over-confident.
> >
> > We'll only do it once— if at all.

The author could have written of an *interesting and flawed concept* or *a concept both interesting and flawed*, but these expressions suggest a concept that is in equal parts interesting and flawed. On the other hand, *interesting, if flawed* suggests the author finds the concept primarily *interesting*, but its *flawed* aspects are significant enough to detract or distract from its *interesting* aspects.

Comment: It could also be rewritten "interesting, **yet** flawed, concept".

Comment: Or "interesting, although flawed, concept" , or "interesting, but flawed, concept" or "interesting, albeit flawed concept". Could also use ... "interesting concept, however flawed it might be."

Comment: Well if we're going to play *that* game, don't forget the inverted alternatives: *while flawed, interesting* , *even if flawed, interesting*, *notwithstanding its flaws, interesting* and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means that although the reader found the concept interesting, he or she also thinks that it may be wrong (flawed) in some areas.

Answer (score 1):

Per the Oxford dictionary for US English:

> flawed :(of an imperfection) mar, weaken, or invalidate (something). The computer game was *flawed* by poor programming

So "interesting, if flawed, concept" means an interesting concept that has imperfections/faults/defects which mar, weaken or invalidate the concept.